# JavaScript Function Not Defined - Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, function, defined

The copy function does the following : If the user enters @ in a text area, it makes a div visible and populates the div with suggestions from an array of keywords. Any array entry that matches what is entered after the @ until a space  is populated in the div. The copy function is attached to the onkeyup event of the text area

All of sudden, the browser reports the function Copy is not defined. I believe this might be a syntax error I am missing. I have looked at my code a zillion times, I can't find a mistake.

```
function copy()
{
    var ta = document.getElementById("ta") ;
    var taarray = ta.value.split(" ") ;
    var lastword = taarray[taarray.length - 1] ;
    document.getElementById('selector').innerHTML = " " ;
    if (lastword.indexOf("@") == 0)
    {       
        selector1(); // Function that makes the div visible
        if (lastword.substr(1).length > 0)
        {
            var f = 0 ;
            while (f <= friends.length )
            {
                if (friends[f].toLowerCase().indexOf(lastword.substr(1).toLowerCase()) != -1)
                {                   
                    var x ;
                    x = "<a onmouseover=projectImage('" + friends[f].split(|)[1] + "') onclick=tagfriend('" + friends[f].split("|")[1] + "')  >" ;
                    x += friends[f].split("|")[0] ;
                    x += "</a>" ;                                       
                    document.getElementById('selector').innerHTML = x + "<br />" ;
                }
                f++ ;           
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the specific error you are getting?

Comment: There's a syntax error in `friends[f].split(|)[1]` - JSHint first next time...

Comment: Make sure your function is defined in a `window.onload` event or under the content of the body in a script tag.

Comment: On the line after `var x;` you're missing quotes around the pipe `|` in `friends[f].split(|)[1]`...  it should be `friends[f].split("|")[1]`

Comment: The Specific Errors is " Uncaught ReferenceError: Copy is not defined "

Comment: Thanks for your participation people. Quotes were missing around the pipe.. As highlighted by gengkev and mVchr

Comment: It says "Copy" is undefined. Your function is defined in lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Your error says that "Copy" is undefined because you defined your function as "copy" (lowercase). Variable and function names are case-sensitive in JS. Yet this is just one of many other errors you have as suggested by  the comments. You should consider using debugging tools like JSLint to resolve problems like these.